# Scala Functional style of converting Array[Int] to Map[Int, Int]

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I want to convert an Array[Int] to a Map[Int, Int] where each key is the element of the array and the respective value is the index of the element in the array.

```
Array(11, 12, 13) => Map((11,0), (12,1), (13,2))
```

Is it possible to do this without using a Mutable map, with a more functional style?

for example:

```
myArray.toMap(implicit def (... ))
```

Comment: This means, of course, that there will be data loss if your `Array` has any duplicate values: `Array(2,3,2)`

Comment: @jwvh Nice spot! Corner and worst cases can matter!

Comment: I will keep this in mind. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
scala> Array(11, 12, 13).zipWithIndex.toMap
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(11 -> 0, 12 -> 1, 13 -> 2)
```

P.S. But use `HashMap`/`HashSet` from Scala  collections wisely to avoid security vulnerabilities on untrusted input under DoS/DoW attacks that exploit [hash collision vulnerabilities](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/hash-collision-vulnerability-in-default-hashmap-and-hashset-implementations/3740) of them directly or indirectly through Scala collections methods that use them under hood: `toMap`, `keys`, `distinct`, `groupBy`, etc..